# jspdf data show on a table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jspdf

I am using jspdf for making html data to table.I make pdf with html data but data not showing as formatted tableMy sample code

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#gen_pdf').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#make_pdf').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,

        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('student_result.pdf');
});
```

and sample table

```
<div class="form-group" id="make_pdf">
     <table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered">
         <tbody>
             <td>Course Code</td>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td>Grade</td>
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

How can I show table data to pdf as formatted table.

Comment: How can I do that?Can you share code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately tables are not supported by jsPDF but there's a third party library that does a really great job it's called jsPDF-AutoTable. It's also very easy to use.

You can download it from here:
https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable